# Getting ANT view for Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers

Tags: eclipse, ant

I use the Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers from the [Eclipse downloads page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), but I just discovered that it doesn't include an ANT view, which the Eclipse classic version provides. So how do I get the ANT view for the "Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers" version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just installed Eclipse Classic, then added the [Eclipse Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) as a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to reinstall eclipse, you can instead install "Java Development Tools"

1. In Eclipse go to Help -> Software Updates -> Available Software
2. Select Java Development Tools and install it
3. Restart Eclipse

source: http://www.christian-kalmar.com/activating-missing-ant-plugin-in-pdt-eclipse/

Answer (score 2):

Rather than installing the entire JDT package we can install the ANT UI component directly using Eclipse's P2 director through the command line as follows

```
    $ cd <your eclipse install folder>
    $ ./eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler -installIU org.eclipse.ant.ui
    Installing org.eclipse.ant.ui 3.5.400.v20130514-1341.
    Operation completed in 19162 ms.
```

[image: Ant UI Installed]

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that some of the builds don't include all of the Ant tools. I'm not sure how to install them manually. So I usually just get the J2EE build (which has them) and install everything else I need from the update sites.

Answer (score 0):

Right click file.  Choose Open As.  In Show View Choose Ant.

Comment: There is no "Open As" option.

Comment: I just downloaded your version and, indeed, there is an Open As function.  Thanks for the vote down though.

Comment: Can you make a screen shot please? I do not see this at all. I see 'Open' and 'Open With' but not 'Open As'..